# Type int[][] of the last argument to method println(Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type

Tags: java

I have the following:

```java
static public void println(Object what) {
    if (what == null) {
        out.println("null");    
        out.flush();
    }
    else if (what.getClass().isArray()) {
        printlnArray(what);
    }
    else {
        out.println(what);
        out.flush();
    }
}


static public void println(Object... variables) {

    for (int i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {
        Object o = variables[i];
        if (o.getClass().isArray()) {
            printlnArray(o);
        }
        else {
            out.print(o);
            if (i != variables.length-1) out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    out.println();
    out.flush();  
}
```

If I call it like this:

```java
int[][] array_2d = {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};
println("array_2d");
println(array_2d);
```

Then I get the error:

> Type `int[][]` of the last argument to method `println(Object...)` doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to `Object[]` to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.

I can't seem to find a way to suppress this warning. Neither do I have any luck with fixing the error. Adding `println(int[][] variables)` is not an option.

I did an attempt in this direction:

```java
enum Skip {
    SKIP
}

static public void println(Object[] variables) {
    println(Skip.SKIP, variables);
}

static public void println(Object first, Object... variables) {

    if (first instanceof Skip) {

    }
    else {
        print(first);
    }
```

But it does not work and would require to much obscure code to get it working.

Can this problem be fixed with reasonable clean code?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem (at least not on Java 14, which version are you using?). Please provide your example as [mcve] (code which will be *complete* so we could copy-paste it and without *any* modifications use it to reproduce *exact* problem you are facing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that invokes on `println` are ambiguous. After all, `println(Object... x)` is just syntax sugar for `println(Object[] x)` with the additional nicety that callers will silently create that array for you if invokes with multiple arguments. This makes invoking `println` with a single value, but that value is an array, ambiguous: Either form is plausible (an array is itself an Object!)

Simple solution is to disambiguate:

```
/*1*/ public void println() {}

/*2*/ public void println(Object o) { ... }

/*3*/ public void println(Object a, Object b, Object... rest) { }
```

Now all forms except `println()` work out and are not ambiguous:

```
println(); // invokes #1
println(x); // invokes #2, and only #2. Even if x is an array.
println(x, y); //invokes #3, with an empty array for 'rest'
println(x, y, a, b, c); // invokes #3.
```

NB: Do NOT write `println(Object a, Object b)` or `println(Object a, Object... rest)` - that would re-introduce ambiguity!

Comment: I still have the problem now when calling `print("a", "b", some_2d_array);` But hitting a case like that is really unlikely that I'm happy with it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The warning occurs because it is ambiguous whether you want to:

- pass the 2D array as one whole `Object` to the varargs:

  ```
  // calling this as if it weren't a varargs method for clarity
  println(new Object[] { array_2d })
  ```

  or;
- "splat" the outer array such that each inner array is one of the varargs:

  ```
  println(new Object[] { array_2d[0], array_2d[1], array_2d[2] })
  ```

If you want the former, cast the 2D array to `Object`. If you want the latter, cast the 2D array to `Object[]`.

```
println((Object)array_2d);
// or
println((Object[])array_2d);
```

Doing either will silence the warning.